# Traversing list of dictionaries and mapping with dataframe columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, list, dictionary, for-loop

### dataframe  uploaded

[data frame](https://github.com/ajayvd/DOUBT_SO)

1. The data frame consist of 3 columns latitude , longitude , & response . The objective
   is to traverse the Response column and in that there is an estimate key
2. estimate key contains multiple arrays , on which i have to pick the (store external id & provider) .
3. while traversing the imp point is (lat&lng) of that particular row have to get mapped with the (store external id & provider ) only with that row .

for example :
[data frame image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMhZg.png)

look at the second row it contains the value ( 34.081613, -84.278921)

printing  the estimate response

```html
{'store-boundary-dsp': {'boundaries': [{'createdAt': '2020-07-15T19:21:03.000Z',
    'name': '801-Primary',
    'selected': True,
    'storeExternalId': '801',
    'tags': []},
   {'createdAt': '2021-09-14T15:24:28.000Z',
    'name': '801-Primary',
    'storeExternalId': '801',
    'tags': ['shiptprimary']}],
  'distances': [{'distance': 2.6, 'storeExternalId': '801', 'unit': 'miles'}],
  'errors': [],
  'estimates': [{'_id': None,
    'amount': 800,
    
    'expires': None,
    'fee': None,
    'noEstimate': False,
    'orderId': '5232197187827800',
    'orderType': None,
    'provider': 'Instacart',
    'ruleApplied': False,
    'serviceType': 'Delivery',
    'storeExternalId': '801',
    'supportsAlternateLocation': False,
    'type': 'delivery'},
   {'_id': None,
    
    'noEstimate': False,
    'orderId': '5232197187827800',
    'orderType': None,
    'provider': 'Shipt',
    'serviceType': 'Delivery',
    'storeExternalId': '801',
    'supportsAlternateLocation': False,
    'type': 'delivery'}],
  'fulfillments': [{'provider': 'Instacart',
    'serviceType': 'Delivery',
    'storeExternalId': '801',
    'type': 'delivery'},
   {'provider': 'Shipt',
    'serviceType': 'Delivery',
    'storeExternalId': '801',
    'type': 'delivery'}],
  'value': ['801']}}
```

-> storing as per requirement ( store external id & provider) & it will look like

(801,instacart) & (801,shipt) now this have to get mapped with the lat longs of 1st row .
& dataframe have to be created .

### data frame

34.081613, -84.278921 ,801 ,instacart

34.081613, -84.278921 ,801 ,shipt

### custom function for this above problem

issue which i am facing is it is getting mapped with all of the rows ,

it must map with only that particular row.

```html
def extract_details_sb_dsp_positive(response):

    res = []

    # Check to ensure first two keys are in the response, otherwise empty list
    if not 'store-boundary-dsp' in response:
        return res

    if not 'estimates' in response['store-boundary-dsp']:
        return res
    tuple_da_required=[]
    count_rows=0
    for i in range(len(data_metering)):
        
        x=data_metering.loc[i, "LATITUDE"]
        y=data_metering.loc[i, "LONGITUDE"]
        list_store=[x,y]
        #print(list_da)
    # Iterate through each estimate
        for estimate in response['store-boundary-dsp']['estimates']:
        # Iterate through each key, value pair for the estimate
            store_id = ''
            providor = ''
            for k, v in estimate.items():
            #keep the count of no of estimates 
            #based on the count copy the lat,lngs,city,state, country,tenantid 
                if k == 'storeExternalId':
                    store_id = v
                if k == 'provider':
                    providor = v
            res.append([store_id, providor,list_store])
            
    return res


# For each cell in the 'RESPONSE' column, extract out the store_id, provider pair
response_values = data_metering['RESPONSE'].apply(extract_details_sb_dsp_positive).tolist()

pair_values = [val for sublist in response_values for val in sublist]
pair_values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
from ast import literal_eval

gh_link = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajayvd/DOUBT_SO/main/so_doubt.csv"   ​
df = pd.read_csv(gh_link).assign(RESPONSE= lambda x: x["RESPONSE"].map(literal_eval))
​
s = df.pop("RESPONSE").str["store-boundary-dsp"].str["estimates"].explode()​
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index)[["provider", "storeExternalId"]])
```

Output :

```
print(out)

    LATITUDE  LONGITUDE   provider storeExternalId
0  37.671080 -92.660949   DoorDash            7510
1  34.081613 -84.278921  Instacart             801
1  34.081613 -84.278921      Shipt             801
2  40.750311 -84.116898   DoorDash            1035
2  40.750311 -84.116898   DoorDash            4883
3  33.164890 -80.034914   DoorDash            3791
4  34.692532 -82.810008  Postmates            5464
4  34.692532 -82.810008   DoorDash            5464
```

Comment: thanks for the one liner solution :) , could you please tell me where i'am going wrong in the custom function .

Comment: You're welcome. I think the major issue is that the parameter/argument received by your function (*which is* `response`), is actually an `str` and not a `dict`. Try to add `response = literal_eval(response)` right after `def extract_details_sb_dsp_positive(response):` and then check.

Comment: sorry ,  if you look at the second row it have to be repeated twice , but in your output code it got joined with the other row.

34.081613, -84.278921 ,801 ,instacart
34.081613, -84.278921 ,801 ,shipt

Comment: Oops, sorry I fixed it. Can you check again ?